# Why did mathematicians name a functional that assigns number to function as a "distribution"?

Tags: analysis, terminology, math-history

Why did people name it as a "[distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics))"? I don't see the reason. My instructor told us don't bother with this strange name, but I guess maybe I will have a better understanding if I know the reasons for the naming.

Comment: But you link an article where it is explained why the word "distribution" was used.

Comment: @Artem Yeah, I know why we need distribution, but the name is weird. Is there any relationship with something like a probability distribution? Or perhaps something is "distributed" in this scenario?

Comment: According to his autobiography, Schwartz introduced the term "distribution" by analogy with a distribution of electrical charge, possibly including not only point charges but also dipoles and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Artem and Will Jagy have pointed out, the Wikipedia article you linked to explains that

> According to his autobiography, Schwartz introduced the term "distribution" by analogy with a distribution of electrical charge, possibly including not only point charges but also dipoles and so on.

One can also look up Jeff Miller's *[Earliest Known Uses of
Some of the Words of Mathematics](http://jeff560.tripod.com/mathword.html)*, where the entry for *distribution* states,

> *Distribution* in the sense of a generalized function was introduced by Laurent Schwartz in his paper *[Généralisation de la notion de fonction, de dérivation, de transformation de Fourier et applications mathématiques et physiques](http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/AUG/AUG_1945__21_/AUG_1945__21__57_0/AUG_1945__21__57_0.pdf)* (1945).

Indeed, in the first paragraph of section 1 of Schwartz's paper we have (translated):

> Thus $\delta(x)$ is not a function, it is a *measure* or *distribution of mass*, of a particularly simple type: it consists of a mass $+1$ placed at the origin.